# How can I create an already defined function that I can add code to when defined in the main program?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm really struggling on how to word this properly, so I'll use an example. Using the p5.js library, there are two functions called setup() and draw(), each of which you define in your main sketch and add code to. However, the setup function automatically runs once, and the draw function automatically loops after the setup function runs.

On top of this, there are keyPressed() and mousePressed() functions which are used in the same way:
`function mouseMoved() { // automatically gets mouse movement }`

I want to know how to use this to implement in my own projects. Can anyone offer me a solution?

Comment: Wrap function with `(...)` and follow with `()`. Example `(function run() {console.log('hi');})();`. Is this what you want?

Comment: It's more about the functionality more than it automatically running, I've done that before but to me the code looked a little tacky and I'd rather put the functioning into a different file, I have a file full of functions and classes I can use and I'd like this to be a part of it